# Will Google+ APIs shutting down affect signing in into Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, login, authentication, google-plus

According to [this article](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-apis-shutting-down-march-7-2019.html), Google+ APIs will shut down on March 7, 2019. Since I am using Google to provide authentication for several web sites (SE sites included), I am wondering if SE network will be affected by this.

**Question:** Will Google+ APIs shutting down affect signing in into Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Google+ API shutdown will not affect our login system at all. We have already been using the generic Google OAuth2 API for some time, which is a completely independent API and is not being discontinued. We've also already updated our system to grab user info from the generic Google user profile rather than the Google+ profile. Users can continue using the Google login option without interruption.